# WKWebView not working on iOS 11, 12 - First launch/installation

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` inside a `UIViewController` that have a URL variable we're passing the url to when initialized from multiple places ( viewControllers ) after passing the url the `WKWebView` keep loading and never triggers the delegates

```
// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
```

And

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

This issue only appears on **iOS 11 and iOS 12** and only for the first installation.

after failure for the first time if you popped the scene and enter it again, it will work again  with no issues.

and this happens only for a specific url, let's call it ( A ) for other urls it works fine from the first time.

what have we tried with no luck

1. debug the url from the first installation ( its fine )
2. debug the delegates from first installation ( its fine )
3. The view controller was implemented programmatically  since its only hold `WKWebView` we switched it to storyboards
4. creating two instance one as `WKWebView` and one as `WebView` and use the `WebView` instance for iOS 11, 12 and `WKWebView` for iOS 13
5. changing the way we set the delegates from `DidLoad` into separated functions.

Summary:
this issue only appears one time on installation for both iOS 11 and 12 and if we enter the scene after that everything works just fine.

Swift version: 5.2
Project iOS support: 11 and above.

And here is the code ( I think it's not useful since it's working fine for iOS 13 and after the first installation )

```
class MicrositeViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!
var micrositeModel: MicrositeModel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.preferences = preferences
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.backgroundColor = .white
    view = webView
    webView.load(micrositeModel.request)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.showProgressHud()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.hideProgressHud()
}

// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let url = (navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.url else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
      //other logic
}
```

And this is how we are using it

```
let micrositeViewController = MicrositeViewController()
micrositeViewController.title = "title"
micrositeViewController.micrositeModel = MicrositeModel(micrositeRequest: .myType, accessToken: accessToken)
micrositeViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(micrositeViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: did you debug token?

Comment: @A.Munzer yes, and it's there everything is there

Comment: Is this happen with all url's ?

Comment: @A.Munzer No just for this one. but they're all the same tested and works 100%

Comment: @A.Munzer No just for this one. but they're all the same tested and works 100%